# Redirecting output for chage

Tags: redhat

I go in as a non-root user. Issue the command;

```
chage -l myaccount
```

I get output. If I Issue the command;

```
chage -l myaccount > tmp.log
```

I end up with a zero length file.

OS And release below;

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.9"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. While chage doesn't redirect the output, you can pipe it to grep looking for "Password expires" THEN you can redirect the output.

```
chage -l myuser | grep "Password expires" > tmp.log
```

This actually saves me a step in my script so I don't have to read through the output line by line.

Still a little irksome that chage won't let me redirect the whole output.